# How to index a dataframe so it can be augmented?

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I am trying to add a new component for residuals to my dataframe for multiple subjects. I can do it individually like so:

```
subjectnew<-subset(Abc, condition=="gram" & subject==51)
subjectnew$resTime<-residuals(AbcModel[[51]])
```

However, if I run this in a loop, trying to augment the original dataframe:

```
for (q in ids) {
   Abc[which(Abc$condition=="gram" & Abc$subject==q),]$resTime<-residuals(AbcModel[[q]])
}
```

...where `ids` are 33 specific subjects (i.e., `ids<-c(51,52,...)`), I get the following error:

```
There were 33 warnings.
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, which(Abc$condition ==  ... :
  provided 18 variables to replace 17 variables
2: In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, which(Abc$condition ==  ... :
  provided 18 variables to replace 17 variables
...
```

Am I using `which` incorrectly to index my dataframe?

Comment: It may be that the resTime column is not being created properly from within the for loop, because it is only attempting to assign values to certain rows. Perhaps creating the column before running the for loop using `subjectnew$resTime <- NA` would help clear up the issue.

Comment: Adding a blank column before the loop with `Abc$resTime<-NA` fixed the problem; thank you :) If you submit the same as an answer, @MattJewett, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be that the resTime column is not being created properly from within the for loop, because it is only attempting to assign values to certain rows. Perhaps creating the column before running the for loop would help clear up the issue.

```
subjectnew$resTime <- NA
```